# Multiple Kernel#local_variables entries with block local parameters

Tags: ruby

I am using this version of Ruby on Arch Linux. I also tried the first code snippet in ruby 1.9, which had the same results.

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]

uname -a
Linux ryantm0j132 3.12.7-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jan 12 13:09:09 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

These three snippets below are separate programs.

When I use block local variables that shadow a variable the local_variables array contains 3 entries:

```
a = 1
puts local_variables.inspect #=> [:a]
proc { |;a|
  puts local_variables.inspect #=> [:a,:a,:a]
}.call
```

If I don't shadow, anything it contains 1 entry:

```
puts local_variables.inspect #=> []
proc { |;b|
  puts local_variables.inspect #=> [:b]
}.call
```

Another example of the block local variable not shadowing anything:

```
a = 1
puts local_variables.inspect #=> [:a]
proc { |;b|
  puts local_variables.inspect #=> [:b,:a]
}.call
```

Is there some reason for these extra entries in the first case? Is it a bug in ruby?

Comment: Hmm what does the `;` do in `|;a|`?

Comment: @Manuel It separates parameters to lambda and local variables.

Comment: I reported this as a bug here https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9486

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug on the [Ruby issue tracker page where I reported it](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9486).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I finally got why there are three of them. That’s out of my competence to decide whether this is a bug.

Let’s take a look at the [`bindings`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Binding.html):

```
b1 = binding
a = 1
puts proc { |b2=binding; a| 
  a = 3
  "T: #{b1}, B: #{b2}, L: #{binding}\n" + 
  "TV: #{b1.eval('a')}, BV: #{b2.eval('a')}, LV: #{binding.eval('a')}" 
}.call
# ⇒ T: #<Binding:0x0000000294ef88>,
# ⇒ B: #<Binding:0x0000000294de58>,
# ⇒ L: #<Binding:0x0000000294dd68>
# ⇒ T: 1, B: 3, L: 3
```

It seems there are three `Binding` objects, each having the local variable name added to the list *if and only it was shadowed*. Binding `b2`, though it is a separate instance, has affected by `a = 3` setting.

Probably it was made to simplify the `local_variables` discounting.

Comment: If I call `binding` twice in a row in the same context level, it produces two separate objects.